# Run function in PHP CLI script after period of inactivity

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, reactphp

I used Symfony2 with the [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle) to create a worker that sends documents to ElasticSearch. Indexing documents at a one-by-one rate is much slower than using the ElasticSearch bulk API. Therefore I created a buffer that flushes the documents to ES in groups of thousand. The code looks (a bit simplified) as follows:

```
class SearchIndexator
{
    protected $elasticaService;
    protected $buffer = [];
    protected $bufferSize = 0;

    // The maximum number of documents to keep in the buffer.
    // If the buffer reaches this amount of documents, then the buffers content
    // is send to elasticsearch for indexation.
    const MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

    public function __construct(ElasticaService $elasticaService)
    {
        $this->elasticaService = $elasticaService;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     *
     * Flush any documents that remain in the buffer.
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Add a document to the indexation buffer.
     */
    public function onMessage(array $document)
    {
        // Prepare the document for indexation.
        $this->doHeavyWeightStuff($document);

        // Create an Elastica document
        $document = new \Elastica\Document(
            $document['key'],
            $document
        );

        // Add the document to the buffer.
        $this->buffer[] = $document;

        // Flush the buffer when max buffersize has been reached.
        if (self::MAX_BUFFER_SIZE <= ++$this->bufferSize) {
            $this->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send the current buffer to ElasticSearch for indexation.
     */
    public function flush()
    {
        // Send documents to ElasticSearch for indexation.
        if (1 <= $this->bufferSize) {
            $this->elasticaService->addDocuments($this->buffer);
        }

        // Clear buffer
        $this->buffer = [];
        $this->bufferSize = 0;
    }
}
```

This all works quite nice but there is a slight problem. The queue gets filled with messages at an unpredictable rate. Sometimes 100000 in 5 minutes, sometimes not one for hours. When there are for instance 82671 documents queued, the last 671 documents don't get indexated before receiving another 329 documents which might take hours. I would like to be able to do the following:

*Warning: Sci-Fi code! This obviously won't work:*

```
class SearchIndexator
{
    protected $elasticaService;
    protected $buffer = [];
    protected $bufferSize = 0;
    protected $flushTimer;

    // The maximum number of documents to keep in the buffer.
    // If the buffer reaches this amount of documents, then the buffers content
    // is send to elasticsearch for indexation.
    const MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

    public function __construct(ElasticaService $elasticaService)
    {
        $this->elasticaService = $elasticaService;

        // Highly Sci-fi code
        $this->flushTimer = new Timer();
        // Flush buffer after 5 minutes of inactivity.
        $this->flushTimer->setTimeout(5 * 60);
        $this->flushTimer->setCallback([$this, 'flush']);
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     *
     * Flush any documents that remain in the buffer.
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Add a document to the indexation buffer.
     */
    public function onMessage(array $document)
    {
        // Prepare the document for indexation.
        $this->doHeavyWeightStuff($document);

        // Create an Elastica document
        $document = new \Elastica\Document(
            $document['key'],
            $document
        );

        // Add the document to the buffer.
        $this->buffer[] = $document;

        // Flush the buffer when max buffersize has been reached.
        if (self::MAX_BUFFER_SIZE <= ++$this->bufferSize) {
            $this->flush();
        } else {
            // Start a timer that will flush the buffer after a timeout.
            $this->initTimer();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send the current buffer to ElasticSearch for indexation.
     */
    public function flush()
    {
        // Send documents to ElasticSearch for indexation.
        if (1 <= $this->bufferSize) {
            $this->elasticaService->addDocuments($this->buffer);
        }

        // Clear buffer
        $this->buffer = [];
        $this->bufferSize = 0;

        // There are no longer messages to be send, stop the timer.
        $this->flushTimer->stop();
    }

    protected function initTimer()
    {
        // Start or restart timer
        $this->flushTimer->isRunning()
          ? $this->flushTimer->reset()
          : $this->flushTimer->start();
    }
}
```

Now, I know about the limitations of PHP not being event driven. But this is 2015 and there are solutions like ReactPHP, so this should be possible right? For ØMQ there is [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/zmqdevice.settimercallback.php). What would be a solution that will work for RabbitMQ or independent of any message queue extension?

**Solutions that I'm skeptical about:**

1. There is [crysalead/code](https://github.com/crysalead/code). It simulates a timer using `declare(ticks = 1);`. I'm not sure wether this is a performant and solid approach. Any ideas?
2. I could run a cronjob that publishes a 'FLUSH' message to the same queue every 5 minutes and then explicitly flush the buffer when receiving this message but that would be cheating.

Comment: Not completely what you are looking for but might be a good in between solution. 
Store the time when you last ran the `flush` command and when you add documents also check the time. If it's been more than 5 minutes flush anyway.

2nd best option is the cronjob IMHO

Comment: The point is, when you don't receive any messages for a long period, you can't check the time and therefore the buffer won't get flushed. A cronjob runs PHP in a different process and can therefore not access the buffer.

Comment: So your running that code in a long running php process? Cause in that case you could probably use signals (just like your number 1 option does) have a look [here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/1/1/taking-control-of-php-pcntl_signal) and [here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/16/1/2/timing-your-signals). These signals are non-blocking, haven't used it myself yet, but it might just be the thing you need for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in my comment you could use the signals. PHP allows you to register signal handlers to your scripts signals (i.e. SIGINT, SIGKILL etc.)

For your use-case you can use the SIGALRM signal. This signal will alarm your script after a certain time (that you can set) has expired. Positive side of these signals is that they are non-blocking. In other words the normal operation of your script will not be interfered with.

The adjusted solution (ticks are deprecated since PHP 5.3):

```
function signal_handler($signal) {
    // You would flush here
    print "Caught SIGALRM\n";
    // Set the SIGALRM timer again or it won't trigger again
    pcntl_alarm(300);
}

// register your handler with the SIGALRM signal
pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, "signal_handler", true);
// set the timeout for the SIGALRM signal to 300 seconds
pcntl_alarm(300);

// start loop and check for pending signals
while(pcntl_signal_dispatch() && your_loop_condition) {
    //Execute your code here
}
```

Note: you can only use 1 SIGALRM signal in your script, if you set the time of your signal with `pcntl_alarm` the timer for your alarm will reset (without firing the signal) to its newly set value.

Comment: Yes, that does the same as the ``crysalead/code`` project I mentioned in my question. But that uses "declare ticks" and I doubt whether interrupting the PHP execution after each statement is a performant solution. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Also, the link you've provided links to a page that explains that using ticks is deprecated. Most mentions of ticks state that using ticks is in most cases an anti-pattern. I'm therefore interested whether there is an alternative.

Comment: Your right, I overlooked the part stated ticks were deprecated. I did some digging and found a non-deprecated alternative. By using `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` you can determine yourself when to check for pending signals i.s.o. running the handler every tick. The adjusted solution will be more performant too.. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I think you don't understand the actual problem I have. I can't poll anything, there is no loop that I can use to check things once in a while. The RabbitMQBundle calls a function whenever a message is received, if I would enter a loop, that would be blocking and ``php-amqplib`` would stop reading from the socket.

Comment: I thought you had access to the long running process yes. In that case I don't think its achievable in PHP to do what you want. The flow you're looking for is achievable in lower-level languages. That's why ØMQ has the kind of method you're looking for. As said before by yourself the cronjob that publishes a message to your queue every 5 minutes is the best option. Migrating to ØMQ for your messaging/queues is another option but I realise it is not what you're looking for.